# Can't update the state after getting the data from API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

initial state is:

```
 const [state, setState] = useState({
    priceType: 0,
    recurrenceType: 0,
    start_date: '',
    end_date: '',
    minCapacity: 0,
    maxCapacity: 0,
    price: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 0,
    days: []
});
```

data which I want to update,
[SpecialPriceEditData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mztLV.png)

I am trying in this way;

```
  useEffect(() => {
    {
        if (SpecialPriceEditData !== null) {
            setState(SpecialPriceEditData)
        }
        setState({ ...state });
    }
}, [SpecialPriceEditData]);
```

But state not getting update,

How to achive this

Thank you..

Comment: `setState(SpecialPriceEditData)` or `setState({ ...state });` aren't updating the state? How so? I don't see any reason for it not to. Also, `setState({ ...state })` is a rather meaningless update. Can you clarify what exactly the issue is and what you are trying to do?

Comment: Maybe it depends on what SpecialPriceEditData receives, try logging SpecialPriceEditData in the useEffect. 
If it's not null in your logging, and your code skips the if statement, then something goes wrong in your if statement

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
 
        if (SpecialPriceEditData !== null) {
        setState({...state , ...SpecialPriceEditData})
        }
  
  }, [SpecialPriceEditData]);
```

Comment: This is likely to render loop if `SpecialPriceEditData` is always a non-null value.

Comment: no its not! SpecialPriceEditData  is dependency. and we update other states in useEffect. if you update same state as dependency in useEffect then you create loop

Comment: can you send me reference? please! I'm 3 years developing react apps and never get loop by setState inside useEffect like this!

Comment: Source is [trivial](https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-update-the-state-after-getting-the-data-from-api-utipdd), just try to do it. ‍♂️

Comment: I said it's *likely* to render loop, but I suppose I neglected to specify it is only likely if `SpecialPriceEditData` isn't a ***stable***, non-null reference... which we've no idea about since OP provided an incomplete [mcve].

Comment: you learned me something new

Comment: you learned me something new

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: The content below base on the guess that `SpecialPriceEditData` is merely a props. If it's not true, I will modify my answer.

According to your code, you will always call setState({...state}) inside `useEffect` regardless of `SpecialPriceEditData` is null or not ;

And because `setState` is [not sync](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-setstate-method-async/), and the `state` value is merely [closure](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/03/11/deep-dive-how-do-react-hooks-really-work/) for `useEffect`, the `state` inside `useEffect` will always remain the original value, so after you call  `setState(SpecialPriceEditData)`, the `state` will not change, and then you call `setState(state)`, the previous state chang request will be ignored by React at next render, keep all the same at last ;

And I guess you want to apply all `SpecialPriceEditData` to `state` when `SpecialPriceEditData` is valid, so you can try:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    {
        if (SpecialPriceEditData !== null) {
            setState(SpecialPriceEditData)
        }
    }
}, [SpecialPriceEditData]);
```

Comment: This is likely to render loop if `SpecialPriceEditData` is always a non-null value.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes you are right. But it will end finally if the render doesn't change the ref of `SpecialPriceEditData`;

Comment: If `SpecialPriceEditData` keeps same ( `===` ), it will not trigger another render.

Comment: We don't know anything about `SpecialPriceEditData` though. Waiting for OP to provide a [mcve]. Anything now is just guess work.

Comment: @DrewReese You are right

Comment: SpecialPriceEditData : https://prnt.sc/kw-lE6xIMes0  ,  SpecialPriceEditData is the data that I am getting from get API.

Comment: Thanks for your time @bbbbbbbboat and DrewReese for giving your time,but this answer is not working,I have also tried this before